How do I parse a string to a Complex number
In the method
public static System.Numerics.Complex Parse(string s, IFormatProvider? provider);

what is requirements for the parameter 's'?
I have tried
string s = "<47; 0>";
Complex value = Complex.Parse(s, null);

I am just getting an OverflowException.
I am expecting an instance of type Complex or a FormatException
It looks like the following line in Complex.cs
if (!double.TryParse(s.Slice(openBracket + 1, semicolon), style, provider, out double real))

includes the ';' in the first parameter in 'double.TryParse'.
How can I prevent this?

There seems to be an actual issue with this method

Try format: (real, imaginary).

I copied the function from Complex.cs and it only worked if I changed a few things: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4GcAox. Lines 31 and 44 in my code.
